# How to get the information of transitive dependencies in a gradle task?

Tags: plugins, gradle, dependencies, task, transitive-dependency

I want to get information of all dependencies (including transitive ones) in a gradle task.

I tried the code:

```
class MyGradlePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

  void apply(Project project) {
    project.afterEvaluate {
      println "  Project:" + project.name
      project.configurations.each { conf ->
        println "    Configuration: ${conf.name}"
        conf.allDependencies.each { dep ->
          println "      ${dep.group}:${dep.name}:${dep.version}"
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

But it only prints the declared ones, no transitive ones.

That means, if my `dependencies` is:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:18.0"
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}
```

It only prints these 3 dependencies, but the `org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3` which is the transitive dependency of `junit:junit:4.11` is not displayed.

How to modify the code to let it show `org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3` as well?

PS: I know `gradle dependencies` task will show everything I want, but I need to get the dependencies information manually and print it in my own format.

Comment: You need to resolve the dependencies, e.g. `project.configurations.detachedConfiguration(deps as Dependency[]).resolvedConfiguration`. See the [gradle-versions-plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin) for an example.

Comment: this is very good, I had the same question and the answer did help me, any idea how can we know the hierarchy? meaning which artifact and it's parent, if there is one?

Answer (score 9):

Finally, I figure it out with follow task

```
class Dep {
  String group
  String name
  String version
  String extention
  String classifier

  Dep(String group, String name, String version, String extension, String classifier) {
    this.group = group
    this.name = name
    this.version = version
    this.extention = extension
    this.classifier = classifier
  }
}

task collectAllDeps {
  def deps = []
  configurations.each {
  conf ->
    if (conf.isCanBeResolved()) {
      conf.getResolvedConfiguration().getResolvedArtifacts().each {
        at ->
           def dep = at.getModuleVersion().getId()
           println at.getFile().getAbsolutePath()
           //          dep = dep1.getComponentIdentifier()
           println "$dep.group:$dep.name:$dep.version"
           deps.add(new Dep(dep.group, dep.name, dep.version, at.extension, at.classifier))
      }
    }
  }
  def json = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(deps)
  json = groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json)
  new File("deps.json") << json
}
```

Comment: Seems that `getResolvedConfiguration` has been removed in more recent versions of Gradle (like `6.3`). I'm not sure there's a direct replacement.

Comment: this helped me a lot thank you. should be the correct answer in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

android studio 3.5

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

1. create a demo android app.
2. add code at build.gradle.
3. terminal : ./gradlew showAllDependenciesDebug

   //task name : showAllDependencies[Flavor][BuildType]

The result show all sdk(s) info,
include that imported by : 'implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])'

```
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.dependencies.ArtifactUtils
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.dependencies.BuildMappingUtils
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformManager
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.publishing.AndroidArtifacts
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.VariantScopeImpl


project.afterEvaluate {
    project.android.applicationVariants.each {variant ->
        project.tasks.create(name : "showAllDependencies${variant.name.capitalize()}", group : "help", description: "Print all sdk(s) infomation. author:sodino") {
            doLast {
                showAllDeps(project, variant)
            }
        }
    }
}

def showAllDeps(def project, def variant) {
        def android = project.android
        def globalScope = android.globalScope
        def gradle = project.gradle
        def set = ArtifactUtils.getAllArtifacts(
             new VariantScopeImpl(globalScope,
                new TransformManager(project,
                                    null,
                                    null),
                                    variant.variantData),
             AndroidArtifacts.ConsumedConfigType.RUNTIME_CLASSPATH,
             null,
             BuildMappingUtils.computeBuildMapping(gradle)
        )
        println "${variant.name.capitalize()} all dependencies.size=${set.size()}" 
        set.eachWithIndex {artifact, idx->
                    def componentIdentifier = artifact.componentIdentifier
                    if (componentIdentifier.displayName.contains(':')) {
                        def modulerIdentifier = componentIdentifier.moduleIdentifier
                        def group = modulerIdentifier.group
                        def name = modulerIdentifier.name
                        def version = componentIdentifier.version
                        println "${idx} : ${componentIdentifier.displayName}"
                    } else {
                          println "${idx} -> ${artifact.artifactFile}"
                    }
        }
}
```

The result:

```
sodino Macbook-pro: MyApplication  sodino$: ./gradlew showAllDependenciesDebug

> Configure project :app

> Task :app:showAllDependenciesDebug
Debug all dependencies.size=65
0 -> /Users/sodino/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/libs/sodino.xiamen.FJ.aar
1 : org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.41
2 : org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.41
3 : androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.1.0
4 : androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0
5 : com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0
6 : androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0
7 : androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0
8 : androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
9 : androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3
10 : androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.1.0
11 : androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0
12 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0
13 : androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.1.0
14 : androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0
15 : androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.0.0
16 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0
17 : androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.1.0
18 : org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1
19 : org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1
20 : org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.41
21 : androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0
22 : androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.1.0
23 : androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0
24 : androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0
25 : androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0
26 : androidx.media:media:1.0.0
27 : androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0
28 : androidx.transition:transition:1.0.1
29 : androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0
30 : androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0
31 : androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.1.0
32 : androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0
33 : androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0
34 : androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0
35 : androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0
36 : androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0
37 : androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0
38 : androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0
39 : androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0
40 : androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.1.0
41 : androidx.core:core:1.1.0
42 : androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0
43 : androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0
44 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.1.0
45 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.1.0
46 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0
47 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0
48 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.1.0
49 : androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.1.0
50 : androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0
51 : androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0
52 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0
53 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0
54 : androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0
55 : androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0
56 : androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0
57 : androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0
58 : androidx.print:print:1.0.0
59 : androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0
60 : androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
61 : androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-solver:1.1.3
62 : org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:1.1.1
63 : org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.41
64 : org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
```

Answer (score -2):

It's an old post but I think it's worth to show how to do it in both single/multi gradle project:

You can use **Gradle scan** or use the built-in **dependencyReport Task** if you don't want to share sensible information with Gradle servers.

In a single project, you can directly use:

```
./gradlew dependencyReport
```

In a multiple project, you can use the same invoked to each subproject:

```
allprojects {
   ...
   tasks.register("allDeps",DependencyReportTask) {}
   ...
}
```